# What is the purpose of Logit function? At what stage of model building process this logit function is used?

Tags: logistic-regression

We have two prominent functions (or we can say equations) in logistic regression algorithms:

1. Logistic regression function.
2. Logit function.

I would like to know:

- Which of these equation(s) is/are used in the logistic regression model building process?
- At what stage of model building process which of these equation(s) is/are used?

I know that logit function is used to transform probability values (which range b/w 0 and 1) to real number values (which range b/w -Inf to +Inf). I would like to know the real purpose of logit function in logistic regression modeling process.

Here are few queries which are directly related to the purpose of logit function in Logistic regression modeling:

1. Has Logit function (i.e. Logit equation LN(P/1-P)) being derived from Logistic Regression equation or its the other way around?
2. What is the purpose of Logit equation in logistic regression equation? How logit function is used in Logistic regression algorithm? Reason for asking this question will get clear after going through point no. 3 & 4.
3. Upon building a logistic regression model, we get model coefficients. When we substitute these model coefficients and respective predictor values into the logistic regression equation, we get probability value of being default class (same as the values returned by predict()).

   - Does this mean that estimated model coefficient values are determined
     based on the probability values (computed using logistic regression equation not logit equation) which will be inputed to the likelihood function to determine if it maximizes it or not? If this understanding is correct then, where the logit function is used in the entire process of model building.
4. Assume that - "Neither logit function is used during model building not during predicting the values". If this is the case then why do we give importance to logit function which is used to map probability values to real number values (ranging between -Inf to +Inf).

   - Where exactly the logit function is used in the entire logistic regression model buidling process? Is it while estimating the model coefficients?
5. The model coefficient estimates that we see upon running summary(lr_model) are determined using linear form of logistic regression equation (logit equation) or the actual logistic regression equation?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of Logit function?

The purpose of the Logit function is to convert the real space [0, 1] interval to infinity.

If you check math Logit function, it converts real space from [0,1] interval to infinity [-inf, inf].

Sigmoid and softmax will do exactly the opposite thing. They will convert the [-inf, inf] real space to [0, 1] real space.

This is why in machine learning we may use logit before sigmoid and softmax function, since they match perfectly.